# PayPal IPN fails to work on my custom store

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

I am using PayPal IPN in Sandbox mode and this code isn't working for some reason.

What I want to happen is where it says "VERIFIED" to do the thing between the brackets. But it isnt and I don't know any PhP but I need this to work for my money.

Here is my store's index.php

```
<head>
    <title>Donation Store | EndersoulsRH</title>
</head>
<body>
    <center>
        <form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
        <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Your Minecraft Username"> <br>
        <input type="hidden" name="itemname" value="VIP">
        <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
        <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="SHW4WRJBFNDQA">
        <input type="image" src="http://www.endersouls.us/img/buynow.png" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal – The safer, easier way to pay online!" width="200px;">
        <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_GB/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
        </form>

        <form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
        <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Your Minecraft Username"> <br>
        <input type="hidden" name="itemname" value="VIP">
        <input type="hidden" name="command" value="warp Ranks Hayno">
        <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
        <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="XU8NQN8EVPMYG">
        <input type="image" src="https://www.endersouls.us/img/buynow.png" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal – The safer, easier way to pay online!" width="200px">
        <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_GB/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
        </form>

    </center>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my paypal ipn.php

```
<?php
    header('HTTP/1.1 200 OK');

    $resp = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
    foreach ($_POST as $parm => $var) {
        $var = urlencode(stripslashes($var));
        $resp .= "&$parm=$var";
    }

    $item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
    $item_number = $_POST['item_number'];
    $payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
    $payment_amount = $_POST['mc_gross'];
    $payment_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
    $txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
    $receiver_email = $_POST['receiver_email'];
    $payer_email = $_POST['payer_email'];
    $record_id = $_POST['custom'];

    $httphead = "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.0\r\n";
    $httphead .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
    $httphead .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($resp) . "\r\n\r\n";

    $errno ='';
    $errstr='';

    $fh = fsockopen ('ssl://www.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);

    if (!$fh) {
        die("Connection to and from PayPal has bee lost");
    } else {
        fputs ($fh, $httphead . $resp);

        while (!feof($fh)) {
            $readresp = fgets ($fh, 1024);

            if (strcmp ($readresp, "VERIFIED") == 0) {
                $command = "warp ranks Hayno";

                require_once("WebsenderAPI.php"); // Load Library

                $wsr = new WebsenderAPI("*****","*****","*****"); // HOST , PASSWORD , PORT

                if($wsr->connect()){ //Open Connect

                    $wsr->sendCommand($command);

                }

                $wsr->disconnect(); //Close connection.
            } else if (strcmp ($readresp, "INVALID") == 0) {

            }

        fclose ($fh);
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: You've just posted your server's public IP and password...

Comment: That IP and password has nothing to do with my password XD

Answer (score 0):

I think your URL is wrong. try to put

```
$fh = fsockopen ('ssl://www.sandbox.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);
```

instead of `$fh = fsockopen ('ssl://www.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);

in your test pay now button also put sandbox.paypal.com/blahglah`

so put sandbox.paypal.com..... instead of paypal.com....

```
// STEP 1: Read POST data

// reading posted data from directly from $_POST causes serialization 
// issues with array data in POST
// reading raw POST data from input stream instead. 
$raw_post_data = file_get_contents('php://input');
$raw_post_array = explode('&', $raw_post_data);
$myPost = array();
foreach ($raw_post_array as $keyval) {
  $keyval = explode ('=', $keyval);
  if (count($keyval) == 2)
     $myPost[$keyval[0]] = urldecode($keyval[1]);
}
// read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
if(function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc')) {
   $get_magic_quotes_exists = true;
} 
foreach ($myPost as $key => $value) {        
   if($get_magic_quotes_exists == true && get_magic_quotes_gpc() == 1) { 
        $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value)); 
   } else {
        $value = urlencode($value);
   }
   $req .= "&$key=$value";
}


// STEP 2: Post IPN data back to paypal to validate

$ch = curl_init('https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr'); // change to [...]sandbox.paypal[...] when using sandbox to test
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Connection: Close'));

// In wamp like environments that do not come bundled with root authority certificates,
// please download 'cacert.pem' from "http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html" and set the directory path 
// of the certificate as shown below.
// curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, dirname(__FILE__) . '/cacert.pem');
if( !($res = curl_exec($ch)) ) {
    // error_log("Got " . curl_error($ch) . " when processing IPN data");
    curl_close($ch);
    exit;
}
curl_close($ch);


// STEP 3: Inspect IPN validation result and act accordinglyq

if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {
    // check whether the payment_status is Completed
    // check that txn_id has not been previously processed
    // check that receiver_email is your Primary PayPal email
    // check that payment_amount/payment_currency are correct
    // process payment

    // assign posted variables to local variablesq
    $item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
    $item_number = $_POST['item_number'];
    $payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
    if ($_POST['mc_gross'] != NULL)
        $payment_amount = $_POST['mc_gross'];
    else
        $payment_amount = $_POST['mc_gross1'];
    $payment_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
    $txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
    $receiver_email = $_POST['receiver_email'];
    $payer_email = $_POST['payer_email'];
    $custom = $_POST['custom'];

$servername = "*****";
$username = "*****";
$password = "*****";
$dbname = "*****";

$nizz = (explode('|', $custom));
$var1 = $nizz[0];
$var2 = $nizz[1];
$var3 = $nizz[2];

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
// DO YOUR QUERY HERE OR WHATEVER YOU WANT


// --------------------



if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {


$email_from = 'mymail@example.com';
//send mail from here to notify yourself

} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
$conn->close();

} else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {
    // log for manual investigation
}
```

Comment: ok. lets go step by step. 1. open sandbox paypal account and enable IPN. 2.set url to your php page 3. look at my code i will do copy paste my code at my answer. make sure your PAY NOW button also have sandbox.paypal.com url.

Comment: I copied and pasted that code and it still didn't work. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.